# Math.Max handle three nullable values

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Below is the sample xml file code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Match>
  <IDCIBILDOBMatch>100</IDCIBILDOBMatch>
</Match>
<VerificationScore>
    <IDDOBScore>180</IDDOBScore>
    <IDAltDOBScore>60</IDAltDOBScore>
</VerificationScore>
```

I want to take the Max value, non-null value, such that if all values are null, the result is null.

```
var dobMatchInformation = "";
                var idALTDOBSCORE = "";
                var idDOBScore = "";
                XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(InputRequest);

                bool Match_CIBILDOBMatch = document.Descendants("Match").Elements("IDCIBILDOBMatch").Any();
                if (Match_CIBILDOBMatch == true)
                {
                    dobMatchInformation = document.Descendants("Match").Elements("IDCIBILDOBMatch").FirstOrDefault().Value;
                }

                var dobscoreInformation = document.Descendants("VerificationScore");
                bool Match_AltDOBScore = document.Descendants("VerificationScore").Elements("IDAltDOBScore").Any();
                if (Match_AltDOBScore == true)
                {
                    idALTDOBSCORE = dobscoreInformation.Select(x => x.Element("IDAltDOBScore").Value).Max();
                }

                bool Match_DOBScor = document.Descendants("VerificationScore").Elements("IDDOBScore").Any();
                if (Match_DOBScor == true)
                {
                    idDOBScore = dobscoreInformation.Select(x => x.Element("IDDOBScore").Value).Max();
                }

                var MAXDOBSCORE = Math.Max(Convert.ToInt32(dobMatchInformation), Math.Max(Convert.ToInt32(idALTDOBSCORE), Convert.ToInt32(idDOBScore)));
```

Math.Max calculation wants to handle null Value. if my current code null value comes means getting error

```
var MAXDOBSCORE = Math.Max(Convert.ToInt32(dobMatchInformation), Math.Max(Convert.ToInt32(idALTDOBSCORE), Convert.ToInt32(idDOBScore)));
```

Comment: If those values are `null` then the issue is with the `Convert.Int32` which will fail.  Either add `null` checking or switch to `int.TryParse`.  When you successfully parse a value add it to a `List<int>` and then call `Max` on that or if it's empty go with a `null` `int?`.

Comment: i tried but not working . can you modified my code @juharr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you only need to attempt to parse to an `int` if you have a value and then you can keep the values in a `List<int>` and then do `Max` or whatever you want if it's empty.  Also `XElement` has an explicit cast to `int` so you don't have to get the `Value` and then convert it.

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(InputRequest);
var values = new List<int>();

bool Match_CIBILDOBMatch = document.Descendants("Match").Elements("IDCIBILDOBMatch").Any();
if (Match_CIBILDOBMatch == true)
{
    values.Add((int)dobMatchInformation = document.Descendants("Match").Elements("IDCIBILDOBMatch").FirstOrDefault());
}

var dobscoreInformation = document.Descendants("VerificationScore");
bool Match_AltDOBScore = document.Descendants("VerificationScore").Elements("IDAltDOBScore").Any();
if (Match_AltDOBScore == true)
{
    values.Add(dobscoreInformation.Select(x => (int)x.Element("IDAltDOBScore")).Max());
}

bool Match_DOBScor = document.Descendants("VerificationScore").Elements("IDDOBScore").Any();
if (Match_DOBScor == true)
{
    values.Add(idDOBScore = dobscoreInformation.Select(x => (int)x.Element("IDDOBScore")).Max());
}

var MAXDOBSCORE = values.Any() ? (int?)values.Max() : null;
```